# ensureIndexVisible not working when grouping is active

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I need to keep the scroll position at bottom when a new row is added. When grouping is not active, ensure indexVisible(INDEX_OF_LAST_ROW,"bottom") is working perfectly fine. But when row grouping is active, ensureIndexVisible is not working and the scroll position goes to top. Does anyone have a quick fix for this?

Comment: The example at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-scrolling-scenarios/#expanding-groups-vertical-scroll-location appears to indicate that, as long as you get the index correct, ensureIndexVisible should work with row grouping.

Comment: @Anurag  when you say grouping is active, do you mean grid is grouped based on a column? or that the group is expanded?

Comment: I meant grid is grouped based on a column @PratikBhat.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the count of grouped nodes and fixed the issue using the below code.

```
    var count = 0;
    this.gridApi.forEachNode(function (node) {
      if (node.group) {
        count += 1;
      }
    });
    this.gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(count, "bottom");
```

By the way, if the row grouping is not there, it can be easily achieved by
`this.gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(this.state.rowData.count - 1, "bottom")`

Comment: this count approach would only work if all your groups are in a collapsed state?

Comment: This approach doesn't depend on whether groups are in expanded or collapsed state.